# How to get one value from other categories in php mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sample data with table is test

```
name | catid | date
------------
abc  |   1
def  |   2
ghi  |   1
jkl  |   2
mno  |   1
pqr  |   3
```

And my query

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE catid = 1 AND catid = 2 AND catid = 3 ORDER BY date DESC
```

How to get value with result is

```
    name | catid
    ------------
    abc  |   1
    def  |   2
    pqr  |   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  catid, MAX(DATE) max_date
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY catID
        ) b ON  a.catID = b.catID AND
                a.date = b.max_date
```

Comment: subquery slows down the system. It isn't necessary in the given scenario. Answer of @Royal Bg seem perfect.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain what if the user wants to list all `catID` and there are more than qoo `catid`?  seeing the OP's order by clause: `ORDER BY date DESC` I think he wants to get the latest name for every `catID`. If you execute the his query, it will not give you the same name because it will randomly selects it especially if you have large database. see this [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Comment: hmm  you are right. But the question is  "How to get one value from other categories" .  So.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain So, *"How to get one value from other categories?"*

Comment: @Royal Bg's answer is perfect. Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, catid FROM test WHERE catid IN (1, 2, 3) GROUP BY catid
```

I think you need the IN operator which is simplier than catid = X OR catid... (and you need OR, not AND)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desired output, this might be the query:

```
select catid, min(name)
from yourtable
where catid between 1 and 3
group by catid
```

But it's hard to know what you want based on the info provided in your question.